# Why can't you find pdf of Y by subbing into pdf of X?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

If given the pdf of X, f(x) and that X = 2Y why is necessary to find the cdf of X then the cdf of Y which you then differentiate to find the pdf of Y? Since X = 2Y isn't it true that x = 2y as well i.e. a given value of x must be twice the value of the corresponding y value? In that cause you would just sub x = 2y into the pdf of X to find the pdf of Y which is clearly not the case. I can't seem to understand this notation as if X = 2Y doesn't that mean x = 2y? Could someone please explain why this is not the case?

Comment: If the random variables are related by $X=2Y$, then it is true that $x=2y$. However, a PDF is a function that can be integrated to find a probability, and when you change variables of integration, you cannot just make the substitution in the integrand. In this case you would also need to substitute $dx$ with $2dy$. You should look up change of variables in integral calculus. You do not need to go from PDF to CDF to CDF to PDF. But you do need to follow the rules of calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example: we have $X\sim U(0,2)$, and $X=2Y$. It should be obvious that $Y\sim U(0, 1)$. Now the pdf of $X$ is given by $$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac12, & x\in (0, 2)\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
and the pdf of $Y$ is given by $$f_Y(y)=\begin{cases}
1, & y\in (0, 1)\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\ne f_X(2y)$$
There's simply no reason for $f_Y(y)=f_X(2y)$ to be true in general.